# Keycloak HTTP 401 Unauthorized while creating new user using spring boot service

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Getting javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized while trying to create new user in keycloak with spring boot service.

In KeycloakConfig class. it is breaking during creating keycloak instance with HTTP 401 Unauthorized. "message": "**javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized**",

Am I missing anything? I dont have any extra role configuration in the keycloak client or realm role.
I was thinking to add ".authorization(...) in KeycloakBuilder.builder but I'm not sure what to specify.

```
public static Keycloak getInstance(User user) {
        if (keycloak == null) {
            keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                    .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                    .realm("myrealm")
                    .username(user.getUsername()).password(user.getPassword())
                    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                    .clientId("myclient")
                    .clientSecret("0a53569564d2a748a0a5482699")
                    .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()).build();
        }
        return keycloak;
    }
```

In service class

```
UsersResource usersResource = KeycloakConfig.getInstance(user).realm("myrealm").users();
        CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = createPasswordCredentials(user.getPassword());

        UserRepresentation kcUser = new UserRepresentation();
        kcUser.setUsername(user.getEmail());
        kcUser.setCredentials(Collections.singletonList(credentialRepresentation));
        kcUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        kcUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        kcUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        kcUser.setEnabled(true);
        kcUser.setEmailVerified(false);
        
        javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = usersResource.create(kcUser);
        System.out.println("kcUser: " + kcUser.toString());
        System.out.printf("Repsonse: %s %s%n", response.getStatus(), response.getStatusInfo());
```

in properties file

```
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.resource=myclient
keycloak.credentials.secret=0a5356444d26a748a0a5482699
keycloak.ssl-required= external
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings= true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to missing imports I assume that `KeycloakBuilder` is comming from package `org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder`

Based on your provided code examples you are trying to instantiate a `Keycloak` instance with an user you just want to create. That user is lack of the privileges to create a new user.

That said you need to create an Keycloak instance with an user that has admin rights / roles. At least "*manage-users, view-clients, view-realm, view-users*"

```
 keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL)
            .realm("master")
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .build();
```

With admin access you are able to create users for several realms.

```
// Create a new user
    final UserRepresentation newUser = new UserRepresentation();
    
    newUser.setUsername("username");
    newUser.setFirstName("fristname");
    newUser.setLastName("lastname");
    newUser.setEmail("username@example.com");
    newUser.setEnabled(true);

    // Now you need to get the realm you want the user to add to and the user ressource
    final UserResource realm = keycloak.realm("nameOfTheRealm").users();
    
   // Create the user for the realm
   final Response createUserResponse = userRessource.create(newUser);

 // check response if everything worked as expected
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the admin account is created under 'myrealm'. You cannot use the default admin account (master realm) to create the user for 'myrealm'

Answer (score 2):

In order for a user to have the right to manipulate and call Keycloak's API, you must set the client role for that user

Step 1: User should create a administrators like "admin" password "abc123" in your client "myrealm"

Step 2: Click **admin** user after move to **Roles mapping** tab and assign some necessary permissions to **admin** user as below

[image]

Step 3: Replace password in .username(**user.getUsername()).password(user.getPassword()**) with "abc123"

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional information that you might wanna know about `phancuongviet`'s answer:

When you trying to set role for user, if you don't see the role that you looking for, try to switch from `filter by realms role` to `filter by clients`, and it will show every other roles.

[image]

Hope it helps.